# My APK is over 50m, can i just move that APK into the expansion file and write a wrapper?

Tags: java, android

My APK that i was getting ready to deploy is 174m, which is over the amount for putting on Google play (50m cap + 2 2g expansion files).

Could i just move my APK into an expansion file and then write a wrapper that is "the apk"

I was thinking that this could be a great way to get around the google play limitations without needed to excise non-critical components to an expansion.

Has anyone else thought of going about this route?

Comment: did you use proguard ?

Comment: If you want the user to install that apk as well, user will have two apps of yours at the end. I guess this is not what any user would like to have.

Comment: @HugoGresse that is outside the scope of the question.

Comment: @MehulJoisar i was trying to think of a way to maybe just put all the guts in the expansion, maybe not have the entire APK in there, the guts or some other component

Comment: So are you trying to say that your APK is over 50 meters?... Enough with the jokes, have you tried to [obfuscate](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/07/optimizing-obfuscating-and-shrinking.html) it?

Comment: @Fallenreaper proguard will help you to reduce the apk file by removing unused method and classes, obfuscating code to method reset() will be a(). It reduce my app to 40% of it size.

Comment: @HugoGresse Yea, that stuff shouldve been used.  Im with a huge dev team.

Comment: @Fallenreaper but you are not sure ? Check you app gradle file to see if `minifyEnabled` is `true`

Comment: @HugoGresse most of the code base is not written in java, so im not sure if proguard will be useful anyways.  We utilize a lot of Imagery, C++, and Javascript / DB files.  I could always check again though

Comment: @HugoGresse I believe that the version of the codebase i am working on right now uses ANT and not Gradle. The newer version utilizes Gradle, but thats not the part im working on which is in the process of trying to release.

Comment: If you are using ANT so you could use proguard anyway, I guess it's not as simple. Good luck anyway with the expansion